# How to add to the Delphi palette a component defined in a unit?

Tags: delphi

I have a pas unit defining a component.

How can I add it to the palette? the only way I know is to include it in a package, is tehre a direct way to do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a package, have a unit that has a procedure named `Register` — the capitalization is important. In that procedure, call [`RegisterComponents`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.RegisterComponents) on the component you'd like to appear on the Tool Palette.

You must use packages. That's the only way the IDE will load the executable code; it cannot execute DCU files directly. If you don't already have some other package to use, you can add your component to the DclUsr package.

With component libraries of any appreciable complexity, there will usually be at least two packages. There will be a run-time package that contains all the components, and then there will be a design-time package that contains the `Register` procedures.

Comment: Isn't the distinction between run-time and design-time packages usually a little more than that? Don't the design-time packages typically contain designers that aren't needed at run-time?

Comment: *"the capitalization is important"* is that true? wow I did not know, I wonder if that has caused me some of the headaches when adding some components to the palette!

Comment: The design-time package should contain all the code that it is used at design-time only (registration, designers, design-time dialogs, object inspector extensions, ecc.).

Comment: Capitalization is important because it is also used by C++ Builder which is case sensitive.