# How to use the range selector component unit in Delphi

Tags: delphi, components

I was searching for a way to implement a range selector in Delphi when I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387690/component-similar-to-trackbar-to-enter-a-range-of-values) on SO. This seems exactly what I need but being new to Delphi and RAD Studio XE6 I have no idea what to do with this code. How do I use this, should I create a New Component from the Components Menu?

Comment: Start with the documentation (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Component_Writer's_Guide_Index)

Comment: [How to add to the Delphi palette a component defined in a unit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398729/how-to-add-to-the-delphi-palette-a-component-defined-in-a-unit)